# How to except error and redirect results into the new file

Tags: python, exception

I have a list of bacterial species and wanted to count their strain's number in FTP server. But some of them are absent in NCBI which cause an error. How I can skip the error and continue counting?

This is the initial code:

```py
output = open("bact_count.csv", "wt")
splist = [s.strip('\n') for s in open("bact_list_refseq", 'r')]
for i in splist:
    sp_name = i.strip('\n')
    req 
=urllib2.Request('ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/refseq/bacteria/{}/assembly_summary.txt'.format(sp_name))
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()
    print(i, '\t', len(str(the_page).split('\\n')) - 3)
output.close()
```

I've tried to use try/except. But it didn't help.

```py
output = open("re.csv", "wt")
splist = [s.strip('\n') for s in open("bact_list_refseq", 'r')]
for i in splist:
    sp_name = i.strip('\n')
    for i in sp_name:
        try:
            req = urllib2.Request('ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/refseq/bacteria/{}/assembly_summary.txt'.format(sp_name))
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            the_page = response.read()
            print(i, '\t', len(str(the_page).split('\\n')) - 3)       
output.close()
```

As a result, I should get the table with 2 columns: species name and their quantity.

Answer (score 0):

When an error occurs, the value of req will not be set, so this means that in your `finally` statement, you are using the value of req from the previous iteration.

You should move the code from your `finally` statement into the `try` statement.

```py
output = open("re.csv", "wt")
splist = [s.strip('\n') for s in open("bact_list_refseq", 'r')]
for i in splist:
    sp_name = i.strip('\n')
    for i in sp_name:
        try:
            req = urllib2.Request('ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/refseq/bacteria/{}/assembly_summary.txt'.format(sp_name))
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            the_page = response.read()
            print(i, '\t', len(str(the_page).split('\\n')) - 3) 
        except:
            continue

output.close()
```

Another thing, you shouldn’t leave the except statement so broad, you should change it to accept only the specific error caused by the missing item.

Comment: I used except Exception. Thank you!

Comment: @DilfuzaDjamalova I’m glad I could be of help! If you found my answer useful, please accept it